# How do I query a MySQL view in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, database

I have created a database view and I would like to show the results in a Drupal Page. The view has some pretty complex SQL behind it, so trying to use the Views module isn't possible.

I just want to do `SELECT * FROM VIEW_X` and display the results on a page in PHP.

I know how to do this in Drupal 6, but how is it done in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible to query views using the DBTNG query builder: if you try to use [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_select/7) with a view, it raises a `PDOException` complaining that the table doesn't exist.

Instead, you'll want to use [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7). Let's assume you created a view named `test`:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM variable;
```

To get the value of `cron_key`, you'd do:

```
$name = 'cron_key';
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM test t WHERE t.name = :name', array(':name' => $name));
$value = $result->fetchColumn(1);
```

The [comment by drclaw on the `db_query()` API entry](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7#comment-7019) gives a number of examples which should help you out with figuring out how to manipulate a `SELECT` query using `db_query()`.

Comment: db_select() works fine with views